# Using "@" to insert multiple lines of strings in StringBuilder

Tags: c#, string

I have a StringBuilder object and wanted to used its Append() method to add this whole string to it:

[image]

so I used "@" and copy pasted that whole string like this, but it gives a lot of errors such as "; expected ", "Invalid Expression '<'" , etc

```
myString.Append(@"COPY-PASTED-THAT_WHOLE-STRING");
```

What is the correct way of adding this string to my string builder object?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Double-quotes (`"`) inside the string you want to paste need to be escaped by being replaced with two consecutive double-quotes, as in `""`. Here's a trick to use:

- Paste your string into a new instance of Notepad
- Replace all double quotes (`"`) with two double quotes (`""`)
- Select and copy the content from Notepad back into clipboard
- Paste it into `@"…"` in your code/text editor

From [C# docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691090.aspx):

> In a verbatim string literal, the characters between the delimiters
>   are interpreted verbatim, the only exception being a
>   *quote-escape-sequence*.

Comment: yes it fixed the errors. So now still if I save this to a file, It will Exactly look like what I had posted in the picture?

Comment: Yes, if ypi save the content of the `StringBuilder` to a file, it will look exactly as your picture.

Answer (score 6):

Even with an `@` prefixing the string, you need to escape any `"` characters, otherwise they will be interpreted as the end of the string literal.

**EDIT:**

e.g.

```
var entity = @"<!ENTITY xsd ""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#"">";
```

Comment: @BDotA: [MSDN has examples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/362314fe.aspx).

Comment: That's not how you escape quotes in a literal string

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `@` syntax to add multiple lines.  But you need to escape the `"`s inside your string by using `""`

For example

`@"<Ontology xmlns=""http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#"""`

If you don't escape them, C# will treat the quote mark as the end of the string.

Answer (score 1):

One option, as others have said, is to escape all of the double quotes (`"`) with a double double quote (`""`).

What I prefer to do, as it makes the code more readable, when adding an XML block as a literal string, is to use single quotes rather than double quotes.  Just put the XML file into a text editor and do a replace all on double quote with a single quote (`'`).

Another option, since your XML literal isn't all that short, is to put it into a file and read in that file at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

You can escape them like this as well...

```
@"<Ontology xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#\""
```